# Sed regex string substitution from terminal

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a log file with a standard format, e.g.:

```
31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom1
31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom2
31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom3
```

The replacement I want to implement is 31*31 to 31 so I'll end up with a log that has only its last line, in this example it will look like:

```
31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom3
```

I wish to perform it on a customized linux machine that has no perl.
I tried to use sed like this:

```
sed -i -- 's/31*31/31/g' /var/log/prog/logFile
```

But it did nothing..
Any alternatives involving ninja bash commands are also welcomed.

Comment: not very sure what `31*31` means here. Could you clarify? Or you just want to print the last line containing 31? Does the file contain other lines?

Comment: @fedorqui: I think the OP confuses wildcards with quantifiers.

Comment: @CommuSoft yes but neither the glob `31*31` nor the regex `31.*31` match any lines.

Comment: @fedorqui: you can enable new line processing in `sed`. The it works. Although it will have side-effects the OP probably doesn't took into account.

Comment: @fedorqui I mean "*" as a wild card, sorry if wasn't specified. Got mixed up with "*" sign at more theoretical CS stuff I'm up with as CommuSoft said,

Comment: @GalB1t may be good to update your question with a proper explanation. You can do it by pressing the [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29367276/edit) button.

Comment: Do **all** lines in the file start with the date? If yes, `tail -1 file` is all you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to keep only the last of consecutive lines that match a pattern is

```
sed -n '/^31/ { :a $!{ h; n; //ba; x; G } }; p' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
/^31/ {    # if a line begins with 31
  :a       # jump label for looping

  $!{      # if the end of input has not been reached (otherwise the current
           # line is the last line of the block by virtue of being the last
           # line)

    h      # hold the current line
    n      # fetch the next line. (note that this doesn't print the line
           # because of -n)

    //ba   # if that line also begins with 31, go to :a. // attempts the
           # most recently attempted regex again, which was ^31

    x      # swap hold buffer, pattern space
    G      # append hold buffer to pattern space. The PS now contains
           # the last line of the block followed by the first line that 
           # comes after it
  }
}
p          # in the end, print the result
```

This avoids some problems of mult-line regular expressions such as matches that begin or end in the middle of a line. It will also not discard lines between two blocks of matching lines and keep the last line of each block.

Answer (score 2):

`*` is not a wildcard as it is in the shell, it is a quantifier. You need to quantify over `.` (any character). The regex is thus:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/31.*31/31/g'
```

(I removed the `-i` flag so you can first test your file safely).

The [`:a;N;$!ba;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) part makes it possible to process over **new lines**.

Note however:

- The regex will match any `31` so:

  ```
  31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom1
  31 Mar - Lorem 31 Ipsom2
  ```

  Will result in

  ```
  31 Ipsom2
  ```
- It will match greedy, if the log reads:

  ```
  31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom1
  30 Mar - Lorem Ipsom2
  31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom3
  ```

It *remove* the second line.

You can solve the first problem by writing:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/(^|\n)31.*\n31/31/g'
```

Which forces the regex that second `31` is located **at the beginning** of the line.

Comment: seems it works while there is no `31` in text (and no 31 at the start of the line/ealier line) like `3 Mar - Lorem Ipsom311`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: the first or the second?

Comment: with you correction it's better but what about internal non 31 starting line ? (OP was not clear about this, sample showing only 31 line so it's ok for me)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for "tail" to get the last line of the file
e.g.

```
tail -1 /path/file
```

or if you want the last entry from each day then "sort" might be your solution

```
sort -ur -k 1,2 /path/file | sort
```

- the `-u` flag specifies only a single match for the keyfields will be returned
- the `-k 1,2` specifies that the keyfields are the first two fields - in this case they are the month and the date - fields by default are separated by white space.
- the `-r` flag reverses the lines such that the last match for each date will be returned. Sort a second time to restore the original order.

If your log file has more than a single month of data, and you wish to preserve order (e.g. if you have Mar 31 and Apr 1 in the same file) you can try:

```
cat -n tmp2 | sort -nr | sort -u -k 2,3 | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

- `cat -n` adds the line number to the log file before sorting.
- `sort` as before but use fields 2 and 3, because field 1 is now the original line number
- `sort` by the original line number to restore the original order.
- use `cut` to remove the line numbers and restore the original line content.

e.g.

```
 $ cat tmp2
 30 Mar - Lorem Ipsom2
 30 Mar - Lorem Ipsom1
 31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom1
 31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom2
 31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom3
 1 Apr - Lorem Ipsom1
 1 Apr - Lorem Ipsom2

 $ cat -n tmp2 | sort -r | sort -u -k 2,3 | sort | cut -f 2-
 30 Mar - Lorem Ipsom1
 31 Mar - Lorem Ipsom3
 1 Apr - Lorem Ipsom2
```